# Send sms from the command line from Ubuntu over an Android connected with gsconnect?

Tags: command-line, android

Is there a command line interface to send an sms from my laptop over gsconnect? There is a GUI, but since I need to automate the process with a script, the GUI is not useful for my purpose.

I run Ubuntu on my laptop and I have an Android smartphone connected to my laptop with gsconnect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I found no answer to the specific question I asked, because the GSConnect suite doesn't include CLI commands.

But I found a workaround in two steps:

1. You can issue adb commands over a bluetooth link. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129817/adb-over-bluetooth-android
2. Once you can use adb, you will find how to send an SMS looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043490/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-a-shell

Hoping this helps.